# Javascript IPhone Application send request or information to server PHP file

Tags: php, javascript, iphone, html

Hello i have iphone app now i want to send request or data to server or PHP file.

Please note: the php file is on another server not on the same server.

How can i send data to server using javascript ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fastest and easiest solution would be including jQuery and use it's post method; http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/